# how to make a text with JSON and a submit button for the value and what property should i use (basically i want to generate form from json object)

Tags: javascript, json

[image]how to make text at the same line of another With JSON object for example: TEXT:Input text, and a submit button that if i write a value inside the input text it automatically write the values for the other (basically i want to generate form from json object) input text how can i do it that was really hard for me to figure it out and i did a research about it but i didnt find anything so can you help.

JSON object:

```
[
  {
    "Object1": {
      "ID": 1,
      "type": "input",
      "color": "red",
      "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
      "value": "",
      "width": "150px",
      "height": "40px",
      "top": "15px",
      "left": "5px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "20px"
      }
    },
    "Object2": {
      "ID": 2,
      "type": "button",
      "color": "blue",
      "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
      "value ": "",
      "width": "150px",
      "height": "40px",
      "top": "70px",
      "left": "5px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "20px"
      }
    },
    "Object3": {
      "ID": 3,
      "type": "input",
      "color": "yellow",
      "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
      "value": "",
      "width": "150px",
      "height": "40px",
      "top": "130px",
      "left": "5px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "20px"
      }
    },
    "Object4": {
      "ID": 4,
      "type": "button",
      "color": "orange",
      "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
      "value": "",
      "width": "150px",
      "height": "40px",
      "top": "190px",
      "left": "5px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "20px"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
    oXHR.open("GET", "JSON.txt", true);
    oXHR.send();

  })

  function reportStatus() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      format(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
  }
  const format = objs => {
    Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {

      const formItem = objs[0][key];
      const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
      if (formItem.type === "button") elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
      else elmn.value = formItem.Text;
      Object.assign(elmn.style, {
        position: 'absolute',
        color: formItem.color,
        width: formItem.width,
        height: formItem.height,
        top: formItem.top,
        left: formItem.left,
        fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
        fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
      });

      document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
    });
  };
```

Comment: You just want to generate a form using JSON or you would like to add some behavior to your form? It not quite clear if you want to add behaviour and if then what kind of.

Comment: @ Pramod Mali i will edit it and add a picture to show you what i mean and no please leave the same code

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/crnbgfj3/

Comment: @PramodMali no please check the picture above

Comment: @PramodMali i want for example name:input text and a submit button that sends it to server site